# Does spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate property validates the columns with table?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-data-jpa, hbm2ddl

In my application i am using below property

```
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto= validate
```

so does it validates schema like if manually i added one new column in my oracle table and not added this column in java entity .

so in this case will it give error on project startup ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's perfectly alright to have columns in a table that aren't mapped. An error would be a missing column or table that's mapped to an entity. Your database doesn't need to be identical to your mappings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. one more thing if in entity i have one string column "descr" and length i have mentioned  =60   @Column(name = "DESCR", nullable = false, length = 60)   and on db side manually i have updated size from 60 to 100 .. so in this case will it give error ?

Comment: @BheemSingh  ok... it means hbm2ddl=validates property.. just validates the columns , in table all columns should be there whatever we have in entity.  correct ?

Comment: @HarishBagora yes.